# Creating dictionary from CVS file using lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pycharm

I have a csv file which contains four columns and many rows, each representing different data, e.g.

```
OID DID HODIS BEAR

 1  34   67    98
```

I have already opened and read the csv file, however I am unsure how I can make each column into a key. I believe the following format I have used in the code is best for the task I am creating.

Please see my code bellow, sorry if the explanation is a bit confusing.
Note that the #Values in column 1 is what I am stuck on, I am unsure how I can define each column.

```
for line in file_2:
    the_dict = {}
    OID = line.strip().split(',')
    DID = line.strip().split(',')
    HODIS = line.strip().split(',')
    BEAR = line.strip().split(',')

    the_dict['KeyOID'] = OID
    the_dict['KeyDID'] = DID
    the_dict['KeyHODIS'] = HODIS
    the_dict['KeyBEAR'] = BEAR

    dictionary_list.append(the_dict)

print(dictionary_list)
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irmjn.png)

Comment: Start by splitting the line... inside your for loop, do `line.strip().split(',')` . I think you can pick up from there ;p

Comment: Please do not post code as images, that makes users unable to copy, to do that, paste the code in the post, to do that hit "edit" under the post then paste it at the below, then highlight it again, than press Ctrl+K, or hit stackoverflow's `{}` menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great Python function for strings that will split strings based on a delimiter, `.split(delim)` where `delim` is the delimiter, and returns them as a list.

From the code that you have in your screenshot, you can use the following code to split on a `,`, which I assume is your delimiter because you said that your file is a CSV.

```
...
for line in file_contents_2:
    the_dict = {}
    values = line.strip().split(',')
    OID = values[0]
    DID = values[1]
    HODIS = values[2]
    BEAR = values[3]
...
```

Also, in case you ever need to split a string based on whitespace, that is the default argument for `.split()` (the default argument is used when no argument is provided).

Answer (score 0):

I would say this as whole code:

```
lod = []
with open(file,'r') as f:
   l=f.readlines()
   for i in l[1:]:
      lod.append(dict(zip(l[0].rstrip().split(),i.split())))
```

`split` doesn't need a parameter, just use simple for loop in `with open`, no need for knowing keys

And if care about empty dictionaries do:

```
lod=list(filter(None,lod))
print(lod)
```

Output:

```
[{'OID': '1', 'DID': '34', 'HODIS': '67', 'BEAR': '98'}]
```

If want integers:

```
lod=[{k:int(v) for k,v in i.items()} for i in lod]
print(lod)
```

Output:

```
[{'OID': 1, 'DID': 34, 'HODIS': 67, 'BEAR': 98}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is using libraries like Pandas, that is powerful in working with tabular data. It is fast as we avoid loops. In the example below you only need Pandas and the name of the CSV file. I used io just to transform string data to mimic csv.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data=StringIO('''
OID,DID,HODIS,BEAR\n
1,34,67,98''') #mimic csv file

df = pd.read_csv(data,sep=',')

print(df.T.to_dict()[0])
```

At the bottom you need only one-liner that chains commands. Read csv, transpose and tranform to dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd
csv_dict = pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv',sep=',').T.to_dict()[0]
```